# Can data still persist if cold nodes reaches maximum shards while hot nodes is not hitting the limit?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

version `7.16.2`

the cold nodes have reaches the set maximum shards per node limit but hot and warm nodes are far from the limit.

there was an issue that before that applications cannot write logs to ES, hence data loss during that time. I haven't check if hot nodes are reaching the maximum shard limit that time but we got the "maximum shards open" error

I'm curious if cold nodes hitting the limit while hot nodes having available space would prevent the write..

Comment: There should be no writes on cold nodes, only indexes migrating to them as a result of an ILM execution. So, since writes (are supposed to) happen only on hot nodes and if your hot nodes haven't yet reached the max shards limit, then writes would not be prevented

Comment: If my cold nodes are reaching the shard limits, indices in warm phase won't be able to move to cold nodes? and therefore would also add up to count in warm phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data should be fine while **only cold node** reached the limit.

If I understand correctly, It would be failed on the ILM `allocate` phase.

Since all `write` requests should first reach the hot nodes,

ILM process should be pending on some waiting/failing phases during the cold node blocked by shards limits; and require further `POST my-index/_ilm/retry` to continue.

On the other hands, if your disk spaces (potentially cpu also) are still available on the cold node, can try increasing the limit:

```
PUT _cluster/settings 
{
  "persistent": { 
    "cluster.max_shards_per_node": "3000" 
  } 
}
```

Or, try to change sharding strategies for hot nodes, like make each primary shard is around 30 ~ 40 GB; and only keep necessary replicas number (1 or 2 should be enough).

Comment: As cold nodes are sourcing their data from snapshots, there's usually no need to have replicas at all, as there is no risk of data loss.

Comment: Yes. Indices are converted to searchable snapshot in `cold` phase.  Thank you for pointing out. Already fixed descriptions. ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/searchable-snapshots.html#using-searchable-snapshots